# Google map - tricking computer to take single click as double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to trick my google map to treat a single click into a double click event?

By default, when you double click, it zooms in, I want to archive this with a single click.

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
```

For marker.addListener('click', function(){});

Possible to trick my computer to treat it as a double click instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
             map.setZoom(12); // zoom
             map.setCenter(e.latLng); // center
  });
```

You can also zoom in:

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
```

or similarly `panTo`